# USQL outputter to write to a SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake

We have an Azure process that calls an API and gets a json file. We store that json on a Data Lake Store. Then I have a USQL activity that reads that file and I want to store that data on a SQL server database also on Azure (not to be confused with a Data Lake Analytics Database: our destination is a regular SQL database).

I am not able (and I am not sure it's possible) to just read the json and store in the database. I think that if it is even possible, then what I should do is create a custom outputter to send the data to the database, but didn't find anything on how to do this by googling. What I did find is [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/837d3a70-5280-4e89-ab46-4596c0553253/outputter-writing-to-sql-db?forum=AzureDataLake) that I didn't fully understand and don't know if it applies to my case as I am using v2 of all the data factory features. The article says at some point

> Therefore the model for writing results into a SQL database is to write output to ADLS and then use ADF or other copy mechanism to load the data into SQL.

So my question is, can I do a custom outputter to load data from a json file in a data lake store into a SQL database? and if so, how?

Answer (score 4):

Data Lake Analytics cannot connect to outside services, such as Azure SQL. You should use the Data Factory for this. The Data Factory is is able to work with json files, if your structure is not too complex. If the JSON is not flat and you need to do a more complex extraction, you can first use an U-SQL script that outputs the data to a csv in Data Lake Analytics. Then you can import that to your (Azure) SQL database. You can trigger the Data Factory pipeline after your Azure process is finished.